# Java ProgressInputStream doesnt popup correctly

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with the ProgressInputStream. The Frame pops up but there is nothing to see.
Thank you and Sorry for my bad english

The problem:
[image: The Problem:]

```
public byte[] createMD5Checksum(String filename) throws Exception {        
    MessageDigest complete = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ProgressMonitorInputStream(MainFrame.this, "Reading: " +filename, new FileInputStream(filename)));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numRead;
        complete = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        do {
            numRead = in.read(buffer);
            if (numRead > 0) {
                complete.update(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
        } while (numRead != -1);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return complete.digest();
}
```

Comment: I guess you are running the creaeMD5Checksum method in the EDT. Try creating a separate thread.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately this was not the solution

Comment: now its working with a new thread but its not closing